# Python - Text Files Reading into a data frame and then appending with part of file name

Tags: python, dataframe, append

Got multiple txt files with filename providing what topic it contains. I need to read the files using glob and then create a data frame with 2 columns, 1 - contents and 2 - topic name (taken from file name)

```
#filename sample - 51132_1.txt
for name in gb.glob('./*_1*'):
    f1 = open(name,"r")  
    rl = f1.readlines()
    topicName = name.split('_1')[0] 
    #print(topicName)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'content':rl})
    df['topicName'] = topicName
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
content topicName
0                                                       .\54468
1                                                       .\54468
2   In article <sheafferC63zt0.Brs@netcom.com shea...   .\54468
3                                                       .\54468
4                                                       .\54468
5                                                       .\54468
6   It had to happen: the old allegation of the "d...   .\54468
```

I am looking for a different output:

```
content    topicname
blah blah  54468
blah blah2 51124
blah blah3 54468
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.basename` to get the file name and then use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
res = []
for name in gb.glob('./*_1*'):
    with open(name, "r") as f1:
        res.append({'content':f1.read(), "topicname": os.path.basename(name).split('_1')[0]})
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob as gb

def process_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        topic = file.split('_1')[0] 
        return {"content": content, "topicname": topic}

data = [process_file(file) for file in gb.glob('./*_1*')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```